# Higher Order Function in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, closures

Recently, I came across the following higher order function example in Wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function#Swift

But I am unable to understand the function. Can anyone explain the code?

```
// generic function
func twice<T>(_ v: @escaping (T) -> T) -> (T) -> T {
    return { v(v($0)) }
}

// inferred closure
let f = { $0 + 3 }

twice(f)(10) // 16
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`twice` takes a function `v`, and returns a new function that compounds `v`'s functionality. Basically, if you have a function `v`, calling `twice(v)(someValue)` is the same as calling `v(v(someValue))`.

```
// inferred closure
let f = { $0 + 3 }

twice(f)(10)
//=> f(f(10)) 
//=> { $0 + 3 }(f(10)) 
//=> { $0 + 3 }({ $0 + 3 }(10)) 
//=> { $0 + 3 }(10 + 3)
//=> { $0 + 3 }(13)
//=> 13 + 3
//=> 16
```